# Are searches by tag broken?

Tags: support, user-interface, searching

I have tried a few variations, and they all take me to the Featured tab.  This would be OK
if I wanted featured questions.  Unfortunately, I want questions (more than 1) which are tagged
nt or co or the appropriate expansion.  Just clicking on the tag or specifying the tag in the search
field results in the above mentioned undesired behaviour?  Did some backend tweak break the
tag facility?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can.  E.g., a recent question on the main page (about a three prime lemma by Lucido) has a group theory tag, which one also sees when clicking through to the question itself.  Clicking on either tag instance takes me to a page with one group theory question listed: a featured question with bounty ( which is not about Lucido's lemma). I was expecting a longer list.

Comment: The choice of tab seems sticky. If you change it once to what you want it should work the next time. Also you can change the tab "preserving" the chosen tag. Furthermore, some tab must be chosen. It is impossible to know which one you want (eg, new or active?). I am not sure what the default is. If it is "featured" I'd agree it is not the most intuitive choice.

Comment: So it's a (to me) user interface change (grumble). Thanks for the enlightenment, @quid. Now I'll try looking for a positive frame for this picture.  If mods so wish, they can remove the question with no complaint from me.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes I guess there was some recent change though I did not keep track;  I was also taken to featured or frequent or something. Something related, I am unhappy about too many tabs being gone when not logged in. Not sure how recent that change is.

Comment: I have also noticed what appear to be recent changes. Most notably, I can no longer perform a search for multiple tags simultaneously without logging in. Such a search converts to a search for the first tag alone.

Answer (score 2):

After performing a search, select "newest" tab (or in the reverse order) - this will work. [Thats what you'll get](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/filters?sort=newest) if you'll search in this way for questions tagged with [filters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/filters) and then (or before) select the "newest" tab.